# How do I return assets with a 404 status code in Play?

Tags: scala, playframework

Currently I have a play application with Scala, in where I have the frontend in the public folder as a SPA.
I have a /404 route in where I want to return the frontEnd with the status code of 404.
However if I write:

```
def returnNotFound(): Action[AnyContent] = Action {
    NotFound(assets.at("index.html"))
}
```

Then I get a compilation error because assets returns an Action, not a Writeable.
So how can I return the index.html in the public folder with the status code of 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `assets.at("index.html")` returns `Action[AnyContent]` which suppose to be return method of `Controller`, hence in order to change status you need to change result from `assets.at` like:

```
def returnNotFound(): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { implicit request =>
    assets.at("index.html")(request).map { result =>
      new Result(result.header.copy(status = 404), result.body)
    }
}
```